# java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "accessClassInPackage.sun.java2d")

Tags: java, oracle, applet

Software del lado del servidor:

1. Oracle Forms : 11g
2. Oracle Database : 11g

Lado cliente:

Internet Explorer 11
Java 8 Runtime Enviroment

Soy un usuario y trato de ejecutar un formulario, pero cada vez que lo intento obtengo el siguiente error.

```
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "accessClassInPackage.sun.java2d")
    at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPackageAccess(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.SecurityManagerHelper.checkPackageAccessHelper(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.AWTAppletSecurityManager.checkPackageAccess(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassLoader.checkPackageAccess(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at oracle.forms.engine.Main.initDesktop(Unknown Source)
    at oracle.forms.engine.Main.start(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.uitoolkit.impl.awt.AWTAppletAdapter.start(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager$AppletExecutionRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "accessClassInPackage.sun.awt")
    at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPackageAccess(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.SecurityManagerHelper.checkPackageAccessHelper(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.AWTAppletSecurityManager.checkPackageAccess(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassLoader.checkPackageAccess(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at oracle.forms.engine.Main.initDesktop(Unknown Source)
    at oracle.forms.engine.Main.start(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.uitoolkit.impl.awt.AWTAppletAdapter.start(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager$AppletExecutionRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Forms Session ID is FORMS_DD.formsapp.41132
The proxy host is null, and the proxy port is 0.
Native HTTP implementation is being used for the connection.
The connection mode is HTTP.
Forms Applet version is 11.1.2.2
RegisterWebUtil - Loading WebUtil Version 11.1.2.2

java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "accessClassInPackage.sun.java2d")
    at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPackageAccess(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.SecurityManagerHelper.checkPackageAccessHelper(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.AWTAppletSecurityManager.checkPackageAccess(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassLoader.checkPackageAccess(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at oracle.forms.engine.Main.initDesktop(Unknown Source)
    at oracle.forms.engine.Main.start(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.uitoolkit.impl.awt.AWTAppletAdapter.start(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager$AppletExecutionRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "accessClassInPackage.sun.awt")
    at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPackageAccess(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.SecurityManagerHelper.checkPackageAccessHelper(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.AWTAppletSecurityManager.checkPackageAccess(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassLoader.checkPackageAccess(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at oracle.forms.engine.Main.initDesktop(Unknown Source)
    at oracle.forms.engine.Main.start(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.uitoolkit.impl.awt.AWTAppletAdapter.start(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager$AppletExecutionRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Forms Session ID is FORMS_DD.formsapp.41137
The proxy host is null, and the proxy port is 0.
Native HTTP implementation is being used for the connection.
The connection mode is HTTP.
Forms Applet version is 11.1.2.2
Java Plug-in 11.181.2.13 x86
Using JRE version 1.8.0_181-b13 Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM
User home directory = C:\Users\Desktop64
----------------------------------------------------
c:   clear console window
f:   finalize objects on finalization queue
g:   garbage collect
h:   display this help message
l:   dump classloader list
m:   print memory usage
o:   trigger logging
q:   hide console
r:   reload policy configuration
s:   dump system and deployment properties
t:   dump thread list
v:   dump thread stack
x:   clear classloader cache
0-5: set trace level to <n>
----------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Tiene toda la pinta de que el JAR de ese Applet no está firmado por una autoridad aceptada, con lo que no permite la ejecución

Comment: ¿y de que forma podría solucionarlo?